# adding a big offset to an os.time{} value

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a Wireshark dissector in lua and trying to decode a time-based protocol field.

I've two components 1)

```
local ref_time = os.time{year=2000, month=1, day=1, hour=0, sec=0}
```

and 2)

```
local offset_time = tvbuffer(0:5):bytes()
```

A 5-Byte (larger than uint32 range) ByteArray() containing the number of milliseconds (in network byte order) since **ref_time**. Now I'm looking for a human readable date. I didn't know this would be so hard, but 1st it seems I cannot simple add an offset to an **os.time** value and 2nd the offset exceeds **Int32** range ...and most function I tested seem to truncate the exceeding input value.

Any ideas on how I get the date from **ref_time** and **offset_time**?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ref_time` is in seconds and `offset_time` is in milliseconds, just try:

```
os.date("%c",ref_time+offset_time/1000)
```

I assume that `offset_time` is a number. If not, just reconstruct it using arithmetic. Keep in mind that Lua uses doubles for numbers and so a 5-byte integer fits just fine.

Comment: Thanks. Using os.date does help ... but offset_time is an (hex) ByteArray.. the internal function do not work for 5-byte ints (just 4 and 8) and arithmetic operations are not supported.
    
    **attempt to perform arithmetic on a userdata value**

Comment: @Hhut, if you can extract the individual bytes from `offset_time`, just do something like `b0+256*(b1+256*(b2+256*(b3+256*b4)))` or in the other order.

Comment: Thanks ... I'd manage to do that, I just needed to make the milliseconds to seconds conversion first ... don't now why but my lua or the wireshark api is limited to 32bit. `local high = chunk(0, 1 ):uint() * 4294967 -- (1<<32)/1000
       local low  = chunk(1, 4 ):uint() / 1000
       local tval = high+low`